# C++ inheritance: Can't access private element of base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, private, public, derived-class

I have a base class:

```
class Base
{
public:
    functions...
private:
    std::vector<float> privateElement;
}
```

and  a derived one:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    functions...
    Derived(anotherElement) : privateElement(anotherElement)
    {

    }
}
```

My problem now is that everytime I try to build my project, the compiler (gcc 4.7.2) always complains about not being able to access `privateElement`, like:

```
class Derived does not have any field named privateElement
std::vector<float> Base::privateElement is private
```

May anybody help me here?

Comment: And what? That's what's `private` is designed to do?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `private` members of base class are **not** *accessible* from derived class.

Now **even if** you fix that and make it `protected`  (or `public`), then this will *still* be ill-formed, because you cannot *initialize* the base's members in the derived class's mem-init-list. It doesn't make sense, because by the time the derived class mem-init-list executes the base's members are *already* initialized, and the syntax `: protectedElement(xyz)` will make the compiler think that `protectedElement` is a member of the *derived* class, not of the *base* class!

See this error **even after making it protected**:

```
main.cpp: In constructor ‘Derived::Derived(std::vector<float>)’:
main.cpp:20:37: error: class ‘Derived’ does not have any field named ‘protectedElement’
     Derived(std::vector<float> v) : protectedElement(v)
                                     ^
```

[Online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d44dfe21cb877e50)

The right way to do this is to define a constructor for the base class, and call this from the derived class initialization-list.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So when using the constructor from the base class, will privateElement be created in the derived class or will I actually be using the object of the base class?

Comment: @BlackMamba: Try doing what you understand from my post. Then do let us know if you face any problem (then you also post the code).

Comment: Okay, this solved my inition problem, but now I face another issue with the constructor:
I want to initialize another object with elements of privateElement, but when I try to use it like this:
Derived(anotherElement) : Base(anotherElement), randomElement(privateElement[0], privateElement[1]) { }
it complains about privateElement being private.
How do I access this alement after initialization?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it without breaking encapsulation would be for the base class to provide a constructor which we can call from derived class :

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    functions...
    Derived(anotherElement) : Base(anotherElement)
    {

    }
}

class Base
{
public:
    Base(anotherElement):privateElement(anotherElement) { }
private:
    std::vector<float> privateElement;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Derived class cannot access private parts of the base class. That's because they are, well, private. Use `protected` if you want the derived class to have access to the base class' members without breaking the encapsulation.

Comment: That's true, I haven't looked at the code in question carefully enough.